# How pass value to Effect in Ngrx - Angular

Tags: angular, angular7, ngrx, ngrx-effects, angular-state-managmement

I'm pretty new to NgRx. I want to pass a value to an Effect. That value is the parameter to be searched in the service.

**Effect TS file**

```js
export class UsersEffects {
  searchParam: string;
  @Effect()
  users$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionTypes.SEARCH_USERS),
    map(action => action.payload), //ERROR doesn't recognize payload
    switchMap((payload) =>
      this.githubSearch.getUsers(payload).pipe(
        map(res => new UserActions.GetUsersSuccess(res)),
        catchError(() => of({ type: '[Users API] Users Loaded Error' }))
      )
    )
  );

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private githubSearch: GithubSearchService
  ) {}
}
```

As you can see I have a method called `getParam()`, which subscribe to a `BehavioralSubject` that contains the search param. I'm not able to call that the `getParam()` method inside of my Effect. Is there another way to do so? or to pass it straight to the `Effect` from a different `.ts` file? Do I use the payload?

**Component TS file**

```js
    onSearch(): void {    
     this.githubSearchService.setSearchParam(this.searchForm.value.searchParam);
            this.store.dispatch(new UsersActions.SearchUsers());
            this.searchForm.reset();
     }
```

**Reducer TS**

```js
 case ActionTypes.SEARCH_USERS:
      return action.payload;
```

**Actions TS**

```
    export class SearchUsers implements Action {
      readonly type = ActionTypes.SEARCH_USERS;
      constructor(public payload: string) {}
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the action payload to achieve this.

`this.store.dispatch(new UsersActions.SearchUsers(searchParam));`

Then map to the action payload in your effect.

```
this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<SearchUsers>(ActionTypes.SEARCH_USERS),
    map(action => action.payload),
    switchMap((payload) => ...)
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for taking your time to help me. I'm getting an error in the reducer. I have updated my questions. ERROR doesn't recognize payload

Comment: it works tho... it just doesn't recognize it so I put it like this ````map(action => action['payload'])```` and it works

Comment: You may need to add the type info: `ofType<SearchUsers>(ActionTypes.SEARCH_USERS)`. This allows the TypeScript compiler to expect the action passed to `.map()` to be an instance of the `SearchUsers` action.

Answer (score 0):

```
onSearch(): void {    
 this.githubSearchService.setSearchParam(this.searchForm.value.searchParam);
        this.store.dispatch(new UsersActions.SearchUsers());
        this.searchForm.reset();
 }
```

You didn't send any value on action your action want a value which type gonna be string

```
 export class SearchUsers implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.SEARCH_USERS;
  constructor(public payload: string) {}
}
```

This is your action that have a constructor and have a payload send the value on action param like this

```
this.store.dispatch(new UsersActions.SearchUsers(searchParams));
```

You didn't send any value to action thats why it not recognize action.payload in effect